# Cannot change Jupyter Lab Theme in container

Tags: docker, jupyter, jupyter-lab

### Problem:

I created a docker image with Jupyter Lab installed for machine learning environment to develop locally.

To avoid using root user in container, I used the same uid in container as my local host machine.

I managed to launch Jupyter Lab in container with command:

```
Jupyter lab --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888
```

However, I cannot change theme of jupyter lab. and It report following errors:

```
[W 14:02:12.974 LabApp] 500 PUT /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/apputils-extension:themes?1572184932897 (172.17.0.1): Failed writing settings (@jupyterlab/apputils-extension:themes): [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.jupyter'
[W 14:02:12.975 LabApp] Failed writing settings (@jupyterlab/apputils-extension:themes): [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.jupyter'
[E 14:02:12.975 LabApp] {
      "Host": "127.0.0.1:8888",
      "Pragma": "no-cache",
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Authorization": "token bbe0ea37f1d54cd21cac85350cf81f7ab831d298ff2ce9ba",
      "X-Xsrftoken": "2|4e33c1b7|8b2a94f61a038e400b6f1d672c8ad95c|1572182770",
      "Accept-Language": "en-gb",
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Origin": "http://127.0.0.1:8888",
      "Content-Length": "237",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.2 Safari/605.1.15",
      "Referer": "http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Cookie": "username-127-0-0-1-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1572184913|23:username-127-0-0-1-8888|44:MGMzNzJmNDAwOWQ3NDQzOWI1ZDgzOTY5ZTUzYTI4NjQ=|e2e38e0740c172241ffd8d95316bbe453cc40fd4e03e8f6530593d746f8d9037\"; _xsrf=2|4e33c1b7|8b2a94f61a038e400b6f1d672c8ad95c|1572182770"
    }
[E 14:02:12.975 LabApp] 500 PUT /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/apputils-extension:themes?1572184932897 (172.17.0.1) 8.73ms referer=http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab
```

The directory '/.jupyter' doesn't even exist in the container.

How can I fix this and change theme to dark? Thanks!

---

### Appendix

Below are complement codes if needed

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3-jupyter AS pre

WORKDIR /repo
RUN apt-get -qqy update && apt-get install -qqy \
    curl \
    npm \
    nodejs

FROM pre AS dev
COPY ./* /repo/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirement.txt
RUN jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/toc
RUN chmod -R 777 /.local
```

requirement.txt:

```
pandas
scipy
scikit-learn
matplotlib
seaborn
jupyterlab
```

How I run the container:

```
docker run -it -u $(id -u):$(id -g) \
               --rm \
               -p 8888:8888 \
               -p 6006:6006 \
               -v /$(pwd):/repo \
               -w /repo \
               --name $(basename $("pwd"))\
               $(basename $("pwd")):latest \
               bash
```

Answer (score 1):

When you launch Jupyter use the `-notebook-dir` switch to specify a home directory for your notebook.  Jupyter will need write access to this directory using the user id that you have chosen to use.  The .jupyter directory will be created automatically and will store configuration options for your Jupyter environment.

You are probably best off choosing a subsidiary directory to one that you mount into the container with your run command.  Note that within the .jupyter directory a jupyter_notebook_config.py file will be created with many options that you may wish to tune.  For example, `c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = False` may be appropriate in your situation.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me to understand how jupyter works better. I fixed it by creating the `'/.jupyter'` folder in Dockerfile and enable current user to write in that folder.